# Labels along x axis disappear when using expand=c(0, 0)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphic

I've a question regarding to the labels of the x-axis. Assume I've the following plot:

```
p <- ggplot(long_form_q, aes(reihe, variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") 

 pneu <- p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue", limits= c(1,3), breaks=c(1,2,3)) + 
 geom_text(aes(label=long_form_textq$value)) +
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y =element_blank())  +
 theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=18, color = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(size=14)) +
scale_y_discrete(labels=c(h_3x3.1="3x3", h_3x5.1="3x5", h_3x9.1 ="3x9"), expand=c(0,0))
```

of the following form:

[image]

How can I change the labels of the x-axis to (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) while using expand=c(0,0) for x ? If I'm using

```
scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0))
```

the labels are vanish

My `dput` is:

```
dput(long_form_q)
structure(list(reihe = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("h_3x3.1", 
"h_3x5.1", "h_3x9.1"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .Names = c("reihe", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"), expand=c(0,0))`   If we had the data it would've been easier, but something like this should work.

Comment: No, the axis vanishes. See edit for dput of my data

Comment: `long_form_textq$value` ? what about this dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're plotting continuous data along the x axis, so the correct scale is `scale_x_continuous()`. The reason the labels are disappearing is because you're erroneously using `scale_x_discrete()`.

```
pneu <- p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue", limits= c(1,3), breaks=c(1,2,3)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label=value)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y =element_blank())  +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=18, color = "black"), axis.text.x = element_text(size=14)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=c(h_3x3.1="3x3", h_3x5.1="3x5", h_3x9.1 ="3x9"),
                   expand=c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = 1:10)

pneu
```

[image]

I didn't have your variable `long_form_textq$value`, so I used `long_form_q$value` instead. Note that it is almost always a bad idea to feed data into ggplot via the `aes()` function. Data should be provided via the `data =` argument.