# How to avoid expand = c(0,0) to crop off axis ticks labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am constructing a Cleveland dot-plot displaying values between 0.0 and 1.0.

I am close to having the plot that I want, but a tiny detail is bothering me. Because I use expand = c(0,0) the last 0 in 1.00 on the x-axis is cut off.

I have tried changing all kinds of settings but without luck.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031425/labels-along-x-axis-disappear-when-using-expand-c0-0) with a similar title to this post does, unfortunately, not help.

Can you help me keep the borders of the plot without cutting off the last zero in 1.00 on x-axis?

reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Tastyness = c(0.6, 0.7, 0.9, 0.95, 0.98),
  Fruit = c("Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Mango", "Peach")
)


ggplot(df, aes(x = Tastyness, y = Fruit)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0.0, 1.0),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.00)
  )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution that works on margins around plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Tastyness, y = Fruit)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0.0, 1.0),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.00)
  ) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(.2,.5,.2,.2),"cm"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe change the labels, so that there are no decimals on 0 and 1:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Tastyness, y = Fruit)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0.0, 1),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.00),
    labels = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1))
```

[image]

Or shift labels horizontally:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Tastyness, y = Fruit)) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0.0, 1),
    expand = c(0, 0),
    breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 1.00)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

[image]